# Ubuntu on Chrome tablet

Tags: asus, chromebook, crouton

I am receiving a gift from my company for years of service. The only gift I was interested in is an Asus Chromebook Flip c434. I have read a few snippets on the web about running Linux on Chrome using any of the following optionsL

A. Linux apps via Crostini.

B. Linux side by side with ChromeOS via Crouton.

C. Dual boot using chrx.

I'm pretty sure the Flip c434 I am getting does not have a huge amount of storage so option "C" may not be the best. I am leaning towards option "B"
Anyone with experience running Ubuntu using Crouton? Pros and Cons? Ease of configuration?

Thanx!!!

Juan

Answer (score 0):

I tried Crouton for a few days until it self-destructed.
Crouton uses the older LTS version of Ubuntu (Xenial). You may or may not be able to upgrade to Bionic Beaver.

Also note that you will have to enable developer mode which will cause issues when you upgrade in ChromeOS.

Your only safe option is to use Crostini.

Chomebooks are good for some people who only use web apps and services, but they are not general purpose computers.

Comment: Thanx for the info. I have a laptop running Kubuntu 19.10 and that truly is enough for me. The Chromebook is a gift..just curious as to what I can get away with on the Linux side. Been reading a little about UbuntuTouch but seems that it would be a bit to resource heavy for the Asus.